# Store form data in more selected tables

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to save data from the form to multiple tables in the database at once by checking their checkbox in the form, for now there are only four in the form, but there will be 15 of them.

With my current code, selecting the desired table and saving data to it works if I select one, if I select more than one at once, the data is always saved only to the last one selected and the previously selected one is skipped, can i ask you for help?

FORM:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">

   <label for="first">Number:</label>
   <input type="text" name="number" id="first">

   <label for="second">Date:</label>
   <input type="text" name="date" id="second">

   <label for="type">Type:</label>
      <select name="ctype" id="type">
      <option value="Photo">Photo</option>
      <option value="Video">Video</option>
   </select>

   <input type="hidden" name="table1" value="no">
   <input type="hidden" name="table2" value="no">
   <input type="hidden" name="table3" value="no">
   <input type="hidden" name="table4" value="no">


   <input type="checkbox" name="table1" value="yes">Table1
   <input type="checkbox" name="table2" value="yes">Table2
   <input type="checkbox" name="table3" value="yes">Table3
   <input type="checkbox" name="table4" value="yes">Table3

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
 <?php
    $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
    $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
    $ctype = $_REQUEST['ctype'];
    $chck1 = $_REQUEST['table1'];
    $chck2 = $_REQUEST['table2'];
    $chck3 = $_REQUEST['table3'];
    $chck4 = $_REQUEST['table4'];


    if($_POST['table1'] === 'yes'){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('$number', '$date', '$ctype')";}
    else{
    echo "ERROR: UCHECKED 1";
    }

    if($_POST['table2'] === 'yes'){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('$number', '$date', '$ctype')";}
    else{
    echo "ERROR: UCHECKED 2";
    }

    if($_POST['table3'] === 'yes'){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table3 VALUES ('$number', '$date', '$ctype')";}
    else{
    echo "ERROR: UCHECKED 3";
    }

    if($_POST['table4'] === 'yes'){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table4 VALUES ('$number', '$date', '$ctype')";}
    else{
    echo "ERROR: UCHECKED 4";
    }


    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "<h3>Data stored in a database."; 

    echo nl2br("\n$number\n $date\n "
    . "$ctype");
    } else{
    echo "ERROR $sql. "
    . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Your php code overwrites $sql variable in each if.

Comment: `save data from the form to multiple tables in the database at once`...why on earth would you need to do that? Duplicating the same data multiple times should never be necessary in any properly-designed database.

Comment: P.S. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and basic SQL syntax errors due to un-parameterised input values - please urgently read [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and correct the way you're building your queries...I'm not sure where you learned to write them the way you've shown in your question, but whoever taught you that did you a massive disservice.

Comment: Also (if you're running PHP older than 8.1), please bring your error-handling into the 21st century. You should add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect` (or `new mysqli`) command, so that such exceptions are thrown automatically by mysqli, so you don't have to tediously check for errors for for every separate mysqli command. And you should _never_ be echoing error data deliberately into the output - that's another big security risk. Let PHP handle the error so that it gets logged to a file (in a live server) or reported (in your test server)

Comment: @ADyson I have several platforms on which I post, for example, I need to know when, with what note and what type individually for each one, that's why I have separate table for each platform, but at the same time I want to be able to add the same thing to multiple tables if I add the same post on the same day, with the same note, type etc.

Comment: Why is it an error if they didn't check a box?

Comment: Why do you have both hidden and checkbox inputs with the same name? Get rid of the hidden inputs and just use `if (isset($_POST['table1']))`

Comment: `I have several platforms on which I post, for example, I need to know when, with what note and what type individually for each one`...surely you just need a "platform" column in a single table, so you can see which platform it's intended for. If you ever end up with multiple tables with the same columns in them, it's a strong indication that your design is denormalised and that the tables should be merged, where the difference between the records which you're representing via separate tables actually should be represented via values in a column in a single table.

Comment: (This kind of design will also make it a _lot_ easier to add new platforms to your list, because then you don't have to make a new table, add new SQL code to your PHP, etc, in order to support that.)

Comment: @Barmar The error is only there for my personal control, it's nothing public, just a personal content manager project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the `$sql` variable after you test each checkbox. At the end if just contains the SQL for the last one that was checked.

Loop over an array with the names of all the checkboxes, inserting all the appropriate ones.

```
foreach (['table1', 'table2', 'table3', ...] as $table) {
    if (isset($_POST[$table])) {
        echo "Inserting into $table<br>";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $table VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("iss", $number, $date, $ctype);
        $stmt->execute();
    } else {
        echo "$table not checked<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with this I managed to achieve exactly what I needed and thank you for all the other advice too, I will adjust and improve everything gradually.